# tell how much data there is in a session in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
@foreach (count(Session::cart()) as $key => $cartItem)
```

//I need to know how many arrays are obtained from this session to use it in an if statement

```
  @if(count($_SESSION['cart']) > 1)
//I try it but its not work
```

Comment: its  @foreach (Session::get('cart') as $key => $cartItem)

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this.

```
@if(count($_SESSION['cart']) > 0)
    @foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $cartItem)
    //write your code here
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: use `@if(count($_SESSION['cart']) > 0)`